# Android device file explorer: Error opening contents of device file: Remote object doesn't exist

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-device-explorer

I tried to write a string in a text file and store it in the SD card of the emulator. It seems successful. But when I double-clicked to open or copy the saved file in Device File Explorer, it shows an error: **Error opening contents of device file "myTestFile.txt": Remote object doesn't exist!**.

```
String toSaveString = "hihi";
        if(Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)){
            try{
                File f = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null),"myTestFile.txt");
                FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(f, true);
                PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(outStream);

                writer.println(toSaveString);

                writer.close();
                outStream.close();

                Log.d("FileLog","File Saved: "+f.getPath());
            }catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }else{
            Log.e("FileLog","SD card not mounted");
        }
```

Are there any ways to open the file? Thank you!

Comment: Click "synchronize" and the file might disappear.

Comment: @martin Thank you for your answer. I tried to click synchronize, and the file still existed. Because there is no operation to delete the file.